# How to make Mongoose model.insertMany insert documents with numerical and ordered ids?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this route in the backend express server:

```
router.route('/fillInformationAssetsSeverityEvaluation').post((req, res) => {
    informationAssetsSeverityEvaluationRow.remove({}, (err) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            // res.json("informationAssets Collection has been dropped!");

        res.json('information Assets Severity Evaluation data has been received on the server side')

        informationAssetsSeverityEvaluationRow.insertMany([req.body[0]], {
            multi: true
        }).then(documentsInserted => {
            console.log('[req.body[0]]: ', [req.body[0]]);
            console.log('documentsInserted: ', documentsInserted);
            console.log('You have succesfully inserted ', documentsInserted.length, ' documents in informationAssetsSeverityEvaluation collection');
        });

    });
})
```

For the sake of simplicity, I am inserting only one document.

> [req.body[0]]

```
{ REF: 'REFSHIT',
    confFin: 'A',
    confRep: 'A'}
```

But, in the real applications, I am inserting multiple documents similar to that.
This consoleLog :

> console.log('documentsInserted: ', documentsInserted);

logs:

```
documentsInserted:  [ { _id: 5d3453afc302d718e4870b53,
    REF: 'REFSHIT',
    confFin: 'A',
    confRep: 'A'}]
```

As you see the id is automatically generated:

```
> _id: 5d3453afc302d718e4870b53
```

What I would like is: The ids of the different documents to be "numerically ordered". I.e:
Document 0 would have id 0
Document 1 would have id 1
Document 2 would have id 2
And so on and so forth.
After having made some research, I found out that I can do this manually by inserting the id manually inside the updateMany objects.
However, since I receive the documents objects from the request body, this is not a viable solution.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after trying four modules and a couple of days of trying for something that should be native to mongodb, I have found a simple solution.  I hope it helps someone. 
1/  Install  [mongoose-plugin-autoinc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-plugin-autoinc)
2/

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { autoIncrement } from 'mongoose-plugin-autoinc';

const connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/myDatabase");

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
    title: String,
    genre: String,
    publishDate: Date
});

BookSchema.plugin(autoIncrement, 'Book');
const Book = connection.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

2/ In my case I have the models defined in models.js and the connection defined in server.js so I had to write this :

```
 BookSchema.plugin(autoIncrement, 'Book');
```

in models.js
and instead of

```
const Book = connection.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

I have:

```
module.exports = {
  informationAssetsRow: mongoose.model('informationAssetsRow', informationAssetsRow),
};
```

And in server.js:

```
const {
    informationAssetsRow,
} = require('./models/models')
```